# Swift: Работа с буфером обмена

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iphone

У меня есть UITextField и UIButton по нажатию которого должно происходить копирование в буфер обмена данных находящихся в UITextField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

примерно так

```
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "Hello world"
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: не забудьте принять